# Cassandra Bound Statements and Memory Leaking

Tags: java, scala, memory-leaks, cassandra, cql

I am using Cassandra prepared statements to execute my queries in a Scala application using the Datastax Cassandra Java driver.

We have conditional logic to check and see if a bound statement should execute based on some internal state of an object. Something to this effect:

```
def updateDatabase(x: String, y: String, z: String) = {
   val bound = statement.bind(x,y,x)     

   if(sequence_nr < current){
      session.execute(bound)
   }
}
```

Does this introduce a memory leak in either our Scala application or in Cassandra? My inclination is to say no but didn't want to make that assumption as I don't fully understand what the driver is doing behind the scenes with the `bind` call.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Should be just GC'ed

Comment: That was my thought as well. I want to make sure that there isn't anything that happened on the Cassandra side when I bind the statement.

Comment: That being said, it still makes more sense to call the `bind` inside the `if`.  Why bind variables to a statement when you don't plan on using it?

Comment: @Aaron Great point Aaron. There's some inheritance going on in the "actual code" so I'll do some refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bind()` method generates a new instance of `BoundStatement` at each invocation, and `session.execute()` does not keep any reference to it, so it will be GC'ed. There is no risk of memory leaks here.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for some Datastax input :)